# PHP Parse big file and INSERT in Database line by line

Tags: php, mysql, fgets

I have some trouble to open big .txt file then insert it in database line by line.

Here is my code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (email, npai) VALUES (?, 1);");
if ($file) {
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
        $query->execute(array($line));
    }
    fclose($file);
}
else
{
    echo "Can't open the file";
    exit ;
}
```

The problem is that after 1.xxx.xxx line insert the script stop without any error message. I tried my script many times and it's never in the same line that it fails so It's not a problem with a special line. It's a 50mo .txt file but after I have some .csv files around 500mo.

If you have some advice !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using mysql then you could simply use

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path_to_text_file' INTO TABLE yourTableName LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`

to insert data into your table from a text file.

In the source text file the values must be separated by tabs and given in the order in which the columns are listed. You can use `\N` to represent missing values.

you can find more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I set display_errors to 1 and I have an error message :

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/EmailNinja/import/npai.php on line 50

I finally use :
set_time_limit (0);

Thanks a lot